# Code for seeing if a website is down?

Tags: php

I'm trying to replicate sites like http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com or http://doj.me. Any ideas about the coding?

Edit: could I also have some source code examples?

Comment: use cURL and see if you get any sort of response at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `get_headers()` and check to see if returned anything but `200 OK`.

You could also try a `HEAD` request, but there is a small chance a server may respond differently than a GET.

Comment: I'm not sure that checking for HTTP 200 is part of the test: it may return a 404, but that still indicates the web server is alive.. What about just checking port 80?

Answer (score 2):

You could try curl to see what response headers you get back from the specified url. Then go from there I guess.