# See if a website if a website is down php

Tags: php, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [curl and ping - how to check whether a website is either up or down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607684/curl-and-ping-how-to-check-whether-a-website-is-either-up-or-down)
>   [Code for seeing if a website is down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568924/code-for-seeing-if-a-website-is-down)
>   [Source code for downforeveryoneorjustme.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572027/source-code-for-downforeveryoneorjustme-com)

How could I make a form in php, that would allow a user to submit a URL, and then find out whether the site they are trying is down or not?

I think this would use cURL but I'm not sure.

Could you provide the source code of how you would do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use curl then read response code / headers to see if they are correct. Sample codes are in manual: http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php